# unable to pass original array in function from main

Tags: c++

I am passing array containing four elements in quicksort function, But
only one element is getting passed 3 ,I assured this by printing `sizeof(a)`
 when execution enters for first time in `quicksort(a,start,end)` the `sizeof`
was printing only 4 and I always pass array like this it works every time 
But I don't know where I am doing wrong here PLease help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int partition_qs(int a[], int start, int end1) {
    int pivot = end1 - 1;
    int pindex = start;
    for (int i = start; i < end1; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[pivot]) {
            swap(a[i], a[pindex]);
            pindex++;
        }
    }
    swap(a[pindex], a[pivot]);
    return pindex;
}
void quicksort(int a[], int start, int end1) {
    cout << sizeof(a);
    if (start < end1) {
        int pind = partition_qs(a, start, end1);
        quicksort(a, start, pind);
        quicksort(a, pind, end1);
    }
}
int main() {
    int a[] = { 3,-1,2,0 };
    quicksort(a, 0, 4);
    //  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
         // cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: Arrays passed as arguments decays to *pointers* to their first element. So the call `quicksort(a, 0, 4)` is actually equal to `quicksort(&a[0], 0, 4)`. And once the array has decayed to a pointer, the pointer is all you have, and `sizeof` of a pointer will return the size of the pointer itself and not what it might point to.

Comment: Are you required to use c-style arrays? If not then you should use std containers instead, because those will solve many problems you have with c style arrays.

Comment: Please see this working great https://ideone.com/fcr7Oo

Comment: Then whats wrong with the above program

Comment: Perhaps it's time you learn how to debug your programs? Use a debugger to step through the code, statement by statement, stepping into the recursive calls and monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: while I was debugging it was happening In first call to quicksort please help @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: It had never happened to me I always do like this Please I am preparing for exam .